Proof of asymmetry of relative entropy (KL-divergence) $D(p∥q) \neq D(q∥p)$
Unlike a real distance measure, relative entropy is not symmetric in the
sense that $D(p(x)∥q(x)) \neq D(q(x)∥p(x))$. It turns out that many information measures can be expressed by relative entropies.
I want to know the method and procedure of proving $D(p∥q) \neq D(q∥p)$.

Is your question answered here?: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/188903/180158 https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/209107/180158

Just the statement of the divergences will tell you they are not symmetric (unless very specific conditions are met)

You need just one counterexample, one can be found at Intuition on the Kullback–Leibler (KL) Divergence

KL isn't guaranteed to be asymmetric. However, Jensen–Shannon divergence is guaranteed to be symmetric.
