# KL divergence vs Absolute Difference between two distributions?

Tags: density-function, kullback-leibler, information-geometry

Why should I use KL divergence over just giving the abs difference from two PDFs?

Comment: BTW, can you tell more about what is "absolute difference" for two PDFs?

Comment: See:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188903/intuition-on-the-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence/189758#189758

Answer (score 1):

Kullback-Leibler (and other information theoretic divergences, the [$f$-divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence)) is linked to the [Fisher Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information): KL is locally an approximation of the Fisher-Rao geodesic distance, which is a Riemannian metric parameterized by the Fisher Information matrix. It has the property to be the only Riemannian metric (up to a multiplicative factor) which is invariant to reparameterization of the parameter space (in case of a parametric distribution).

Also, and this is important here, the divergence KL (and $f$-divergences) can be seen as **diverging by the 'right' amount with respect to 'information' / statistical uncertainty**: if you have a parametric distribution, paramaterized by $\theta$, and you estimate $\hat{\theta}$ with an unbiased estimator, then [the Cramer-Rao lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) tells you that $\mathrm{var}(\hat{\theta}) \geq \frac{1}{I(\theta)}$, where $I$ is the Fisher Information matrix parameterizing the KL divergence $\mathrm{KL}(\theta \| \theta + d\theta) \approx \frac{1}{2}\theta^\top I(\theta) \theta$.

[Information Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_geometry) is the field which investigates this kind of questions.

If you require a symmetry, you either symmetrized KL, it is called the [Jeffreys divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics)), or use Hellinger (which is also a $f$-divergence and a proper metric distance).

Answer (score 1):

The empirical value of KL divergence is what maximum likelihood estimation tries to minimize. That is,
$\max_\theta \sum_{i=1}^n \log p(X_i|\theta)$  is equivalent to $\min_\theta \sum_{i=1}^n \log \frac{q(X_i)}{p(X_i|\theta)}$ (under regularity conditions).

If you wonder why this is related to KL divergence, note that $KL(q || p_\theta) := E_q[\log \frac{q(X)}{p(X|\theta)}]$.
Here it is assumed that $X_i$'s are i.i.d. samples from the distribution $q$.

And maximum likelihood estimators have good properties.

### (In response to another answer)

@mic
(I can't comment yet, so let me add this here)

> It has the property to be the only Riemannian metric (up to a multiplicative factor) which is invariant to reparameterization of the parameter space (in case of a parametric distribution).

Could you add a reference to support this? Because as far as I understand, this property has been proved *only* for the space of **finite-dimensional, discrete** distributions. (Well, maybe this is due to my limited knowledge, so one should check out anyway)

### Edit

From an engineering point of view, there are alternatives to KL divergence too. One such an example is called Pearson divergence.