# Understanding intuitive difference between KL divergence and Cross entropy

Tags: intuition, information-theory, kullback-leibler, cross-entropy

I know there are related questions already asked, for example [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357963/what-is-the-difference-cross-entropy-and-kl-divergence).

I also know the following:

- KL divergence $D_{KL}(P\Vert Q)$ is given as:

$$\begin{align}
D_{KL}(P\Vert Q) & = -\sum_xP(x)\log\left(\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}\right) \\
& = \sum_xP(x)\log\left(\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right) \\
& = \sum_xP(x)\log(P(x))-\sum_xP(x)\log(Q(x)) \\
& = -\underbrace{\sum_xP(x)\log\left(\frac{1}{P(x)}\right)}_{\text{Entropy } H(x)}\underbrace{-\sum_xP(x)\log(Q(x))}_{\text{Cross entropy } H(P,Q) } \\
 & = -H(X)+H(P,Q) \qquad\qquad...\text{equation(1)}\\ 
\end{align}
$$

- Cross Entropy is given as

$$H(P,Q)=-\sum_xP(x)\log Q(x)$$

(Please correct me if I am incorrect in above equations.)

Knowing all this, I want to build more precise intuition behind the difference.

[Wikipedia defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) KL divergence as follows:

> **KL divergence** of P from Q is the expected **"excess"** surprise from using Q as a model when the actual distribution is P

I believe the word "excess" refers to term $-H(X)$ in equation (1) and we can drop it (essentially dropping $-H(X)$) to get definition for cross entropy:

> **Cross entropy** of P from Q is the expected <s>**"excess"**</s> surprise from using Q as a model when the actual distribution is P.

**Q1.** Am I correct with this?

Also, [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cross-entropy-for-machine-learning/) defines cross entropy as follows:

> If we consider a target or underlying probability distribution $P$ and an approximation of the target distribution $Q$, then the cross-entropy of $Q$ from $P$ is the number of **additional** bits required to represent an event using $Q$ instead of $P$.

I believe this is wrong. Above definition should be of KL divergence and the word **additional** refers to $-H(x)$ term in equation (1). If we drop it (and hence $-H(x)$), we get the definition for cross entropy:

> - **Cross entropy** of $Q$ from $P$ is the number of **<s>"additional"</s>** bits required to represent an event using $Q$ instead of $P$.
> - **KL divergence** of $Q$ from $P$ is the number of **"additional"** bits required to represent an event using $Q$ instead of $P$.

**Q2.** Am I correct with these interpretations / definitions (in terms of bits requirements)?

**Update**

I came across [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/265989) awesome answer, and after reading it, I guess I was correct in about interpretations. The answer states:

> $D_{KL}(p\Vert q)$ measures the average number of extra bits per message, whereas $H(p,q)$ measures the average number of total bits per message.