# Are Dispersion and Entropy Related?

Tags: probability, variance, entropy

So for a system, a dispersion is the measure of how the population deviates from the mean. Intuitively the more the dispersion in the system the more the disorder i.e. entropy. A jar of marbles with only red colors have 0 dispersion (if we measure dispersion by color) as well as 0 entropy. However the following scenerio confuses me in terms of dispersion and entropy:

> Say a class has 2 students. Both the students obtain 10 marks in some test. The average of the class now is 10 while the variance/dispersion is 0. The entropy on the other hand is not 0 which is counter intuitive. 
>   $$\mu=\Sigma \ p(x_i)x_i=0.5(10)+0.5(10)=10$$
>   $$\sigma^2=\frac{\Sigma(x_i-\mu)^2}{N}=\frac{(10-10)^2+(10-10)^2}{2}=0$$
>   $$H(x_i)=\Sigma \ -p(x_i)\log(p(x_i))=0.5\log(2)+0.5\log(2)=1$$

Comment: Have a look at this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483535/how-to-include-the-observed-values-not-just-their-probabilities-in-information/485555#485555   where it is shown that variance can be seen as a kind of entropy! How useful that is, is another question.

Comment: I see _dispersion_ as a vague general concept that can be made precise in several different ways. One of those is variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to calculate entropy from the *sample* (just as your mean and variance are sample mean and variance as well). However, it's a *function* of the distribution, in this case the PMF. Let $X$ be the RV that denotes the grade a random student gets. You need the PMF of $X$ to calculate the actual entropy. But, you can still estimate it using the empirical PMF, which is:
$$\hat p_X(x)=\begin{cases}1 &, x=10\\0 &,\text{else}\end{cases}$$
And the empirical entropy would be:
$$\hat H (p)=1\times\log 1=0$$

Comment: I quite didnt understand it. Why my computation of entropy for the sample is wrong? Is it possible to elaborate the answer a bit.

Comment: Sure, it's not correct because you're using the correct probability mass function. What is your distribution of grades in the classroom? You're saying that the grade is 10 with 1/2 prob, and the grade is again 10 with again 1/2 prob.

Comment: But I used the same 1/2 prob for both in the mean formula and it checks out. Right?

Comment: It'd check out as well when you do $1/3\times10+1/3\times10+1/3\times10=10$, but would it be correct? Define your RV, e.g. X = grade of student. And then, define your distribution. I don't see two different values of $X$ with probabilities 1/2.

Comment: I see. So my mean formula is wrong?

Comment: Yours is sample mean, which is $\hat \mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, it's not the expected value, because you don't have the distribution.

Comment: essentially both 10 & 10 are distributed uniformly. So if we have 3 students all with 10 grades, then the uniform distribution will assign 1/3 to each ..right?

Comment: I am quite eager to know why cant we say that grades of 10 is uniformly distributed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107454/discussion-between-gunes-and-genivi-learner).