# Why use KL divergence if the true distribution is never known?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, kullback-leibler

The KL divergence for Bayesian is information gain or loss when you sample from some distribution rather than another, where one of them is the true distribution.

The problem is you never know the true distribution and the sampling distribution is not the same as the theoretical distribution.

Comment: KL is used in the context of MLE, so we don't consider KL in isolation. Earlier discussion might give some ideas. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392372/why-does-the-bayesian-posterior-concentrate-around-the-minimiser-of-kl-divergenc

Comment: KL is used in the context of MLE, so we don't consider KL in isolation. Earlier discussion might give some ideas. (Mehmet Suzen) See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392372/why-does-the-bayesian-posterior-concentrate-around-the-minimiser-of-kl-divergenc.

Comment: but Bayesians reject the MLE?