# Clarifying notation for the Kullback-Leibler divergence in terms of expectations

Tags: notation, kullback-leibler

We know that for discrete variables 
\begin{equation}
D(p(x),q(x))=\mathbb{E}_{p}\left(\log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right)
\end{equation}
where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are probability mass functions. Can this be extended to
\begin{equation}
D(p(x,y,z),q(x,y,z))=\mathbb{E}_{p}\left(\log\frac{p(x,y,z)}{q(x,y,z)}\right)
\end{equation}
?
where now $p(x,y,z)$ and $q(x,y,z)$ are joint probability mass functions. Is the notation correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The way you've written KL divergence using expectations is valid for any pair of distributions defined on the same space (not limited to discrete values; also works for reals, vectors, etc.). Notation looks fine to me, as long as you specify that $D(\cdot, \cdot)$ means KL divergence. Everyone writes things a little bit differently.

Comment: Yes, [and see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188903/intuition-on-the-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence/189758#189758)  for an explanation and interpretation of that expectation.

Comment: @user20160: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer?
[Better to have a short answer than no answer at
all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/)
Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, that's correct. The way you've written KL divergence using expectations is valid for any pair of distributions defined on the same space (not limited to discrete values; also works for reals, vectors, etc.). Notation looks fine to me, as long as you specify that (⋅,⋅) means KL divergence. Everyone writes things a little bit differently. – user20160

---

I've created this answer from a comment so that this question is answered. [Better to have a short answer than no answer at
all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/)