# How can I prove that KL-divergence is not symmetric?

Tags: self-study, kullback-leibler

How can I prove that KL-divergence is not symmetric?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I did that. Still couldn't find any mathematical proof.

Comment: Hint: One example suffices! So calculate one example and see. You can find one example in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188903/intuition-on-the-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence/189758#189758

Answer (score 1):

It would suffice to show that with a single example. One possibility is as follows:

Define
$$
P(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \text{with probability } 0.5 \\
-1, \text{with probability }  0.5
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
Q(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \text{with probability } 0.1 \\
-1, \text{with probability }  0.9
\end{cases}
$$

You can easily verify that $D_{KL}(P||Q) = 0.5*\ln(0.5/0.1) + 0.5*\ln(0.5/0.9)$ and $D_{KL}(Q||P) = 0.1*\ln(0.1/0.5) + 0.9*\ln(0.9/0.5)$ and they are not equal.

Comment: Is that also applies to the continuous space?

Comment: Yep. You can make an example along the same lines.

Comment: I get lost because of the integral instead of summation...

Comment: Try two normal distributions with different standard deviations.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You can let P be a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1, Q be another normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 2, and compute the KL distance for P||Q and Q||P..

Comment: Yeah, I meant I'm not sure how to plug this into the formula... Can you please tell me? Thanks!

Comment: Try to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution and plug the density with $\sigma=1, \mu=0$ as P and same density with $\sigma=2, \mu=0$ as Q to compute KL(P||Q). Then swap the roles of P and Q to compute KL(Q||P).