How do you choose to put a distribution on the right or left of KL divergence?
I always thought of KL divergence as a distance metric between distributions, much like Earth-Movers distance. But I can no longer ignore the asymmetry. A real distance metric is symmetric.
How should I interpret the asymmetry? And if I have two distributions that I want to measure the KL between how do I decide whether to put one in the right or left argument of the KL[Q||P]?

If you indeed want to "measure the distance," then perforce you need a distance--and KL isn't it.  Otherwise, the answer depends on what you want to accomplish.  Could you please clarify which version of this question, then, you are trying to ask?

The KL-divergence is equivalent to an area, which is the product of two lengths.  You may benefit from reading our lengthy tutorial paper: https://www.mdpi.com/2673-9984/5/1/22

@whuber I changed my question slightly to clarify. I mean if I want to measure the KL between two distributions how should I decide to put one distribution on the right or left.

It depends on what you want to measure.  Maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188903/intuition-on-the-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence answers your questions?  If not, then please be specific about what it does not answer.
